# Ordenar object en AngularJs con orderBy

Tags: javascript, angularjs

He seguido este tutorial: https://justinklemm.com/angularjs-filter-ordering-objects-ngrepeat/

Pero solo ordena por un atributo y me gustaria ordenar por varios.

Este es mi object:

```
var object = '{"Spoofing":{"name":"Spoofing","value":55,"rankingValue":5.75},"Modification":{"name":"Modification","value":70,"rankingValue":4},"Byzantine":{"name":"Byzantine","value":80,"rankingValue":8.75},"Location":{"name":"Location","value":20,"rankingValue":7}}';
```

Me gustaria ordenar por rankingValue y value a la vez

Comment: Se ordena una lista de objetos, no un objeto... no me queda claro qué quieres conseguir

Comment: en el ejemplo solo puedo ordenar por un atributo y me gustaria mas de 1 atributo

Comment: 1) ¿Por cuál de los dos atributos se debe ordenar primero? ¿Por `value` o por `rankingValue`? 2) Fíjate que el filtro personalizado del post que pusiste (`orderObjectBy`) recibe un solo atributo. Para poder hacer el orden por ambos atributos, tiene que recibir ambos, de una manera similar a una de las formas de como recibe atributos el filtro `orderBy: orderBy:['value','rankingValue']` (en este caso, asumiendo que primero se ordena por `value` y después por `rankingValue`).